# Styling each feature of a layer individually

Tags: geoserver, sld

I’ve a PostGIS table which is published as a Geoserver layer. Every feature in the table has some attributes that should style that feature (e.g color, size, opacity, external graphic url, ... etc).

I can create an SLD document and let it read its styling attributes from the table using `<PropertyName>`, but the problem is more complex than this, for example: some points features need to be styled as a simple circles, while some other need to be styled as external-graphic images. And from the SLD Reference, the SLD PointSymbolizer must have either `<Mark>` or `<ExternalGraphic>` element, for that reason I should create two rules one for the simple point symbolizer and the other for the external-graphic point symbolizer, and should add a filter to each rule so that it deals only with the appropriate features, something like:

```
<FeatureTypeStyle>
    <Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqual>
                <ogc:PropertyName>is-external-graphic</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqual>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
                <Mark>
                    <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
                    <Fill>
                        <CssParameter name="fill">
                            <ogc:PropertyName>fill-color</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </CssParameter>
                    </Fill>
                </Mark>
                <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
    <Rule>
        <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqual>
                <ogc:PropertyName>is-external-graphic</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqual>
        </ogc:Filter>
        <PointSymbolizer>
            <Graphic>
                <ExternalGraphic>
                    <OnlineResource
               xlink:type="simple"
               xlink:href="smileyface.png" />
                    <Format>image/png</Format>
                </ExternalGraphic>
                <Size>6</Size>
            </Graphic>
        </PointSymbolizer>
    </Rule>
</FeatureTypeStyle>
```

My question is: Is there any better solution that is more dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

If you set up a single rule with an `ExternalGraphic` followed by a `Mark` then only the first one that can be drawn will be drawn.

So this rule draws faces or dots depending on the existance of the existance of the jepg file:

```
     <PointSymbolizer>
        <Graphic>
          <ExternalGraphic>
                <OnlineResource
           xlink:type="simple"
           xlink:href="smileyface.jpeg" />
                <Format>image/png</Format>
            </ExternalGraphic>

          <Mark>
            <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">
                <ogc:Literal>#FFFFFF</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">
                <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </Mark>
          <Opacity>
            <ogc:Literal>1.0</ogc:Literal>
          </Opacity>
          <Size>
            <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
          </Size>

        </Graphic>
      </PointSymbolizer>
```

So if you can fill the image name in with a file that doesn't exist (null.png should work) then the mark will be drawn. There is an [`if_then_else` function](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#control-functions) that could be useful if you don't have an explicit file column.

Comment: Is there a way to read the styling of each feature from its database record?

Comment: Yes, look around at other questions here